# Como "apagar" uma imagem da tela

Tags: java, animação

Nesse código eu gostaria de apagar a imagem que coloquei anteriormente e não que fique uma em cima da outra.

```
    Graphics g = getGraphics();
    Graphics bbg = backBuffer.getGraphics();

    bbg.drawImage(fundo.getImage(), 0, 0, this);

    for(int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
    {
        ImageIcon playerMoving = new ImageIcon("Imagens/andando-" + i + ".png");

        bbg.drawImage(playerMoving.getImage(), 0, 400, this);
    }

    g.drawImage(backBuffer, 0, 0, this);
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente da seguinte forma:

```
g.clearRect(x, y, width, height);
```

> Limpa o retângulo especificado preenchendo-o com a cor de fundo do
>   superfície de desenho atual. Esta operação não usa o modo de pintura
>   atual.
>
> Começando com o Java 1.1, a cor de fundo das imagens offscreen
>   pode depender do sistema. Os aplicativos devem usar `setColor` seguido
>   de `fillRect` para garantir que uma imagem fora da tela seja limpa para
>   uma cor específica.

[Clique aqui para ver a documentação!](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#clearRect(int,%20int,%20int,%20int))

**[ATUALIZAÇÃO]**

Nesse código acima, isto vai funcionar, pois está pintando o mesmo `canvas` dentro de um `for`.

Existem várias formas de realizar esta animação!

Segue um exemplo utilizando o `repaint()` de um `JComponent` através de uma `Thread`:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.ImageObserver;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Animation extends JComponent implements Runnable, ImageObserver {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 333L;
    /**
     * Controla/Conta qual frame está sendo exibido
     */
    public int frame = 0;
    /**
     * Entre as animações
     */
    public int delay = 99;
    /**
     * Sequencia de imagem que vamos exibir
     */
    Image[] split = new Image[5];
    /**
     * Responsável por redesenhar a tela!
     */
    Thread animatorThread;
    /**
     * Inicializando as sequencia de imagens e Thread que realiza o controle
     */
    public void init() {
        split[0] = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("0.png");
        split[1] = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("1.png");
        split[2] = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("2.png");
        split[3] = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("3.png");
        split[4] = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("4.png");
        animatorThread = new Thread(this);
        animatorThread.start();
    }
    public void run() {
        while (frame != 999) {
            /**
             * Re pinta a tela 
             */
            repaint();
            frame++;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(delay);
            } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void paint(final Graphics g) {
        /**
         * Utilizamos o resto da divisão por cinco para pegar a posição
         */
        int i = frame % 5;
        // e printa a imagem
        g.drawImage(split[i], 10, 10, this);
    }

    public static class Graphics2DDrawImage {
        public static void main(String[] a) {
            JFrame window = new JFrame();
            window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            window.setBounds(30, 30, 300, 300);
            final Animation animation = new Animation();
            window.getContentPane().add(animation);
            window.setVisible(true);
            animation.init();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: clearRect limpa imageicon tambem? Acho que só desenhos, mas imagens acho que não limpa. um simples repaint já seria suficiente.